# Is there a way to set up field description inheritance in Google Dataform?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dataform

Assume the following SQLX definition for BigQuery:

**test_join.sqlx**

```
config {
  type: "table"
}

SELECT
  s1.sales_id,
  s1.sales_value,
  s1.customer_id,
  s2.customer_name
FROM ${ref("source_1")} AS s1
LEFT JOIN ${ref("source_2")} AS s2
ON s1.customer_id = s2.customer_id
```

Assuming that both source_1 and source_2 tables have definitions for all table fields, is there a way for test_join table to inherit field descriptions from the two source tables?

I have scanned the Dataform documentation on [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/), but the only reference to field descriptions I could find is where you manually specify them in the config{} block.

** EDIT **

I've forgotten to mention that the documentation actually does mention how to [reuse the column description](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/document-tables#reuse_column_documentation_in_with_includes) using js code. However, they are still manually specified.

What I'd like to do is to read the descriptions of the fields from the source tables and apply those to joined tables.

** EDIT 2 **

In case somebody is looking for it in the future - I don't think what I'm trying to accomplish will be currently possible. I was hoping I could get js to pull the column names and descriptions using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS from BigQuery and then pass the results as an object to the config block. However, according to the other [documentation repository](https://docs.dataform.co/guides/sqlx):

> "Dataform executes all JavaScript and SQLX code in a Dataform project
> inside a sandboxed environment that has no access to the database,
> data, or network."

The only alternative possibility I can think of right now, is to run something on GitLab/GitHub side as a part of CI that would read the schema and save the object with names and descriptions into a file in the "inlcudes" folder.